# Formatting name suffixes in email address display name

Tags: email

Consider the following email address with a display name:

```
"Sue Smith, PhD" <drsmith@example.com>
```

RFC5322 doesn't provide any definitions about the contents of the display name (beyond the basic definitions of word characters and quotes).

However, I've observed that it seems to be common practice in many mail clients to parse names containing commas as *Last Name, First Name*. In these clients, the example `Sue Smith, PhD` tends to be interpreted as first name "PhD", last name "Sue Smith". This occasionally leads to annoying UI issues in those clients. For example, Gmail displays things like this (until I manually correct the name in the address book):

[image]

Omitting the comma also has various client-dependent effects. The most common I've seen is interpreting `Sue Smith PhD` as first name "Sue", last name "Smith PhD" (or first name "Sue Smith", last name "PhD").

My question is: Is there a safer format for names with suffixes that can increase successful interpretation by a wider range of mail clients, given that there doesn't seem to be any official standard format for display names?

Note that, ideally, the suffix would be kept in the display name. Removing the suffix removes the ambiguity but isn't ideal.

Comment: Parse out qualifications & discard? They are not titles, like Mr., Ms., or Dr.. They are 'qualifications'. They don't belong in any form of address. You might write to me as Dr. Tetsujin, but never Tetsujin, PhD.

Comment: Regardless of whether they belong there or not, lots of people put them there (and do not want to remove them), and so I'm looking for a formatting option to recommend.

Comment: Then… the formatting option I recommend is to remove vanities & use only titles.

Comment: Yeah... that's all I've been able to think of, too. :-/

Comment: [OT] I *have* used suffixes like "Jr." and "Sr." when addressing people in writing before, fwiw -- although I'm not actually sure if it's correct. But it didn't feel awkward.